# Fail Scrapy - It provides an empty output

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I'm scrapping a website and I use the correct xpath of the objects but I get an empty result.
I use the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http.request import Request
from indicators.ESGIndicators import ESGIndicators
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider,Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from lxml import html

class mySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "YALE"
    allowed_domains = ["epi.envirocenter.yale.edu"]
    start_urls = (
        'https://epi.envirocenter.yale.edu/epi-indicator-report/WWT',
        )

    def parse(self, response):
        return Request(
            url='https://epi.envirocenter.yale.edu/epi-indicator-report/WWT',
            callback=self.parse_table
        )

    def parse_table(self,response):
        for tr in response.xpath('//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div/div/div[3]/table[2]/tr'):
            item = ESGIndicators()
            item['country'] = tr.xpath('td[1]/a/text()').extract_first()
            item['data1'] = tr.xpath('td[2]/text()').extract()
            item['data2'] = tr.xpath('td[3]/text()').extract()
            item['data3'] = tr.xpath('td[4]/text()').extract()
            item['data4'] = tr.xpath('td[5]/text()').extract()
            print(item)
            yield item
```

I don't get any error but it doesn't scrap anything. I tried with tdoby in the xpath and without it, but it doesn't work.

Has anyone any idea about the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should double check your xpath expression `//*[@id="block-system-main"]/div/div/div/div[3]/table[2]/tr`. In scrapy syntactically valid xpath/css expressions that don't catch any elements on the page will return an empty list without throwing an error, so the whole loop inside `parse_table` is skipped. Try to debug the target page using `scrapy shell https://epi.envirocenter.yale.edu/epi-indicator-report/WWT` in the command line.

Comment: I get "module" object is not callable. But it is not the error because if I debug another page that I have scrapped, I get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use simple XPath expressions as possible:

```
for tr in response.xpath('//tr[contains(@class, "epi-row-territory")]'):
```